# How to install Oracle Express 11gR2?

Tags: oracle

I need a Step By Step guide for Installing Oracle Database Express Edition version 11g Release R2 on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.1 LTS 64 bit Edition

Comment: I have installed oracle express 10.2 on ubuntu 14.04, it works well, but seems oracle express 11.2 didn't release any package for ubuntu ...

Answer (score 16):

Uber ultimate guide to installing of Oracle 11g XE on modern Debian like distro you can find at (**VERY HUGE** with high amount of **workarounds**, that is why I can't paste article here):

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639

Another valuable sources (hey! these are not links from top 20 web search! I spend 3 evening on reading these blogs, they are really good, but mostly duplicate above `forums.oracle.com` link):

- http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits
- http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html
- http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/06/trouble-shooting-oracle-11g.html
- http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/installing-oracle-11gxe-on-mint-and-ubuntu/
- http://www.len.ro/work/oracle-11g-release-2-xe-on-ubuntu-12-04/
- http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/ora-00845-memory_target-error-installing-oracle-xe-on-mint-and-ubuntu/
- http://blog.oracle48.nl/oracle-11g-amm-memory_target-memory_max_target-and-dev_shm/
- http://d.hatena.ne.jp/t2y-1979/20111017/1318858143
- http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.com/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

One thing that kill a lot of my time is **ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system** error which I fixed by `d.hatena.ne.jp` blog tips:

```
$ sudo vi /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora
$ sudo vi /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/initXETemp.ora 

#memory_target=418381824
pga_aggregate_target=200540160
sga_target=601620480
```

Another error that I fix and that doesn't mentioned by above links is:

```
  System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
  Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/desktop/listener/alert/log.xml
  Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
   TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
     Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted

  Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

when start listener by:

```
  /bin/su -s /bin/bash oracle -c '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl  start'
```

I fix it by commenting line:

```
#      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
```

in `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora`.

Next I read [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm) to unlock `HR` test user which automatically created during installation of Oracle 11g XE...

Rest of the docs can be found at [Database Express Edition Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/index.htm)

Comment: This answer is good enough for a knowledge-base entry. The one thing that remains is: Please fix the grammar and lose the leet-speak!

Comment: Sorry for language, I am not a native English speaker...

Comment: I make some changes, hope you like text more...

Comment: I found the post on forums.oracle.com to have fantastic info. But it's not particularly well formatted, and it could be better organized. I wrote an article based on it, but I made some additions (and subtractions) and improved formatting. [Installing Oracle on Ubuntu](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/oracle-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 5):

I used this guide to install it on Ubuntu Server 12.04 and it worked perfectly.

http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.ca/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I see here that you can download a Linux x64 edition : [Oracle Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html).

Once you get this .zip, open a terminal and type :

```
unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
```

You should see a RPM package. Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, you will need Alien. If you don't have it, type the following instructions in a terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Once it's installed, type this :

```
alien -i oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Done !

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Alien does finish the installation, but then there's no service, no (Oracle) user and nothing running!

Comment: Didn't work me either. My opinion, and it's as good as any opinion for now, is that it's since the oracle installation is very complex and alien is aimed at simple software.

Comment: Your instruction is not enough to install Oracle on Ubuntu. Clearly you didn't test it.

Comment: poissbly you forgot this part.. `You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database.`