# Oracle in Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, sql

Can I install Oracle SQL Developer or Oracle Express Edition in Ubuntu 12.10 (32 bits) using Java 7? If not, what's the "best" SQL Integrated development environment in this platform?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself, but you can find an installer for other operating systems (like Ubuntu) on the official Oracle page.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/otherplatform-installnotes-1719935.html (in this case Oracle Developer)

There is also a short description how to install it.

> To install and run:
>
> - Ensure you have a JDK installed, if not, download here (or get details from your hardware vendor)
>   (click 'Download JDK 6.0 Update ', where  is the latest update)
> - Download the file above
> - Unzip sqldeveloper.zip
> - cd sqldeveloper
> - sh sqldeveloper

Comment: Doesn't work for Java 7!

Comment: Maybe you can try to install it with the RPM package of Oracle. You can find a way how to do it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/198163/how-to-install-oracle-express-11gr2

Comment: Even in 32 bits! Lol

Comment: YOu can download the RPM here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldevlinux-installnotes-1719934.html But I don't know, if it's a 32 or 64bit version. And I have to register to find it out. Just try it.