# Is a .RPM file, like Oracle XE, meant to be used in Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, rpm

I am a Windows user, I've used Linux for some time but only as a secondary OS. Now I am using Linux more than Windows. I wanted to install SQLDevelopr and Oracle XE on my Ubuntu (it's the version of Linux that I do tests, install  sereral RDBMs and technologies to study. I came across a situation where those softwares, SQLDeveloper and Oracle XE are provided only as .RPM files. It seems that they weren't mean to be used in Ubuntu because I have to make conversions and etc. I would like to know if the following impression that I have is true.

Impression: When developing a system for Linux, companies are opinionated about the distribution of Linux that they will support, and to get across this we developers can TRY to install that system on an unsupported Linux distribution by alternative means that are NOT RECOMMENDED by the company that created the sofware.

I am asking about the concept of .rpm files and if is normal to convert it to .deb to install on debian distributions. I don't care how to install make the conversion and stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Oracle 18c (Enterprise Edition) on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121649/how-to-install-oracle-18c-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-18-04) or [How to install Oracle Express 11gR2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198163/how-to-install-oracle-express-11gr2)

Comment: No my question is conceptual. I am considering the concept of RPM files and if it's recommended to make the conversion and install it on debiean distributions. In another words, if I install .rpm on debian and the sofware present bugs, can the company argue that it was because I am using in a linux distribution that they didn't support?

Comment: "No my question is conceptual. " That makes it a matter of opinion. " In another words, if I install .rpm on debian and the sofware present bugs, can the company argue that it was because I am using in a linux distribution that they didn't support?" of course. Mind that we are community driven and rely on the community. Not on companies. Basically: we do not use RPM unless absolutely needed. By the way: there are community maintained DEBs for Oracle XE.